# Program terminates if I use scanf

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer

I am trying to implement the timer in code, All the example that I found are using `while(1)` or `for(;;)` but when I tried with using `scanf` my program terminates. Is it getting any value on `stdin` because if I use `scanf` two times then timer is called two time before exiting from program.
Here is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <time.h>


#define SIGTIMER (SIGRTMAX)
#define SIG SIGUSR1
static timer_t     tid;
static timer_t     tid2;

void SignalHandler(int, siginfo_t*, void* );
timer_t SetTimer(int, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int t;

    printf("SIGRTMAX %d\n", SIGRTMAX);
        printf("SIGRTMIN %d\n", SIGRTMIN);

    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigact.sa_sigaction = SignalHandler;
    // set up sigaction to catch signal
    if (sigaction(SIGTIMER, &sigact, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Establish a handler to catch CTRL+c and use it for exiting.
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact, NULL);
    tid=SetTimer(SIGTIMER, 1000);

    struct sigaction sa;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = SignalHandler;
    // set up sigaction to catch signal
    if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sa failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Establish a handler to catch CTRL+c and use it for exiting.
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    tid2=SetTimer(SIG, 1000);

   // for(;;);  or while(1) Working properly

    scanf("%d", &t); /// Program terminates
    return 0;
}

void SignalHandler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{


    if (signo == SIGTIMER) {
        printf("Command Caller has ticked\n");

    }else if (signo == SIG) {
        printf("Data Caller has ticked\n");

    } else if (signo == SIGINT) {
        timer_delete(tid);
        perror("Crtl+c cached!");
        exit(1);  // exit if CRTL/C is issued
    }
}
timer_t SetTimer(int signo, int sec)
{
    static struct sigevent sigev;
    static timer_t tid;
    static struct itimerspec itval;
    static struct itimerspec oitval;

    // Create the POSIX timer to generate signo
    sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev.sigev_signo = signo;
    sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tid;

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sigev, &tid) == 0)
    {

        itval.it_value.tv_sec = sec / 1000;
        itval.it_value.tv_nsec = (long)(sec % 1000) * (1000000L);
        itval.it_interval.tv_sec = itval.it_value.tv_sec;
        itval.it_interval.tv_nsec = itval.it_value.tv_nsec;



        if (timer_settime(tid, 0, &itval, &oitval) != 0)
        {
            perror("time_settime error!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("timer_create error!");
        return NULL;
    }
    return tid;
}
```

So, How can I resolve this problem ?
Any help would be Appreciated.
Thanks, Yuvi

Comment: C or C++? (filler to make SO happy)

Comment: I think signals are same for C & C++ AFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal interrupts scanf. If you add `perror('scanf')` after scanf output will be:

```
SIGRTMAX 64
SIGRTMIN 34
Command Caller has ticked
Data Caller has ticked
scanf: Interrupted system call
```

If you replace `scanf` with:

```
do {
    errno = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
} while(errno == EINTR);
```

scanf will be retried when it fail with `Interrupted system call`.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely cannot use `printf` and `perror` in a signal handler.  They are not re-entrant.

Also, it's possible that `scanf` will return with an error if your program receives a signal while in it.  If `scanf` returns EOF, check `errno`, it will probably be `EINTR`.

Comment: I know these functions are not `async-safe` that is just an sample code to understand functionality :)