# scanf function and EINTR signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, scanf, eintr

I am working on Linux platform.
I have a console based multi-threaded application which loads a multi-threaded shared object library for other functionalities.
The shared object library internally opens a serial port for communication.
The library uses 'open', 'read' and 'write' Linux system calls for serial communication. Serial communication uses signal-handler to receive data.
The main thread in console application waits on 'scanf' statement, to get input from user.

Whenever there is any activity on serial port, signal are generated due to which the 'scanf' call is interrupted with EINTR (interrupted system call).

Is there any way by which 'scanf' would not be interrupted because on read-write operations on serial port ?

Comment: EINTR is a errno not a signal

Comment: You can try `NONBLOCK` for getting the input. It will not help you to avoid that.

Comment: yes, EINTR is a errno.

Comment: below is my code snippet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program terminates if I use scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086760/program-terminates-if-i-use-scanf)

Comment: g_SerialFileDescriptor = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY, 0);
if (g_SerialFileDescriptor < 0) 
{
    //error
}
else
{
  /* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
  saio.sa_handler = OSAL_Serial_Receive;
  saio.sa_flags = 0;
  saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
  if(sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL) < 0)
  {
    // error
  }
}

Comment: is there any other way by which scanf would not be interrupted due to signals ?

Comment: @Pratham: If you install the signal handler with the [`SA_RESTART`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) flag, `read()` and `write()` calls will not return `EINTR` errors in Linux; neither will the `scanf()` family of standard I/O functions (as they use `read()` internally). See [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) section *"Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers"* for details. Although this behaviour is system-specific, all other Unix-like systems I've used behave the same way.

Comment: SA_RESTART works, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the signal handler with the [`SA_RESTART`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) flag, `read()` and `write()` calls will not return `EINTR` errors in Linux; neither will the `scanf()` family of standard I/O functions (as they use `read()` internally). See [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) section *"Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers"* for details. Although this behaviour is system-specific, all other Unix-like systems I've used behave the same way. –  [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal)